# Classification with data having more features and only having positive examples

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have data with 500 features and 40 examples (40x500). Among the features 490 are Binary and 10 are integers. These are positive examples(They belong to the same class). I want to extract the important features from the data. As I know the source of the data and what it is about, I know some of the important features. What can I do about this?

Comment: Are you trying to build a model to _predict_ something (supervised ML), or do you want to find relationships in your data set (unsupervised ML)?

Comment: I want to do both.

Comment: Your question is too broad for Stack Overflow's format.  If you had a specific programming question then you could ask that.

Comment: Let's suppose I want to building a model to predict the future examples. Then how should I proceed? Thank you

Comment: Look into random forests.

Comment: You might look into [One-class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification)